# Connecting to Mongodb within private VPC with Nodejs Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, mongoose

I have a VPC, within the VPC:

1. Private database Mongodb instance. Security inbound linked to my public node 
   security instance.
2. Public NAT instance.
3. Public nodejs application instance, which goes through my NAT instance

I am able to ssh into the Mongodb instance through my nodejs instance.
I am able to download and am running a mongodb on my private database. 
But not sure of the connection string from my nodejs instance to connect to the mongodb private instance.

I have: mongoose.connect('mongodb://username:password@xx-x-x-xx:27017/admin');
error message:
MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [xx-x-x-xx:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED xx-x-x-xx:27017]

my mongodb has only a private ip, and thinking that's why it's not connecting? Do I have to go through my NAT instance some how?

Anyone connect to a private Mongodb instance through a NAT?

I've connected before by not going through a private VPC..

Comment: A bit confusing. You mean you have a VPC with a public and a private subnet? Nodejs application server and NAT gateway in public subnet with MongoDB in private subnet? Is `public node security instance` the same instance as `Public nodejs application instance`? Also, why are you going through the NAT gateway when you're still in the same internal network?

Comment: Yeah sorry. I have 3 subnets in the VPC. MongoDB instance in private subnet, NAT instance in its own public subnet, nodejs server instance in it's own public subnet. Node server going through the nat instance to reach the Mongodb instance. I watched a video and was told the best way to launch a database for security was to do it this way. I am able to ssh into Mongodb instance and download Mongodb, but not sure the connections string since the instance is private.  Do I need to do it this way?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification :) Technically you don't have to go via the NAT gateway to MongoDB. This makes the routing a bit messy for such a simple setup and doesn't improve security. (also, is this an EC2 instance acting as a NAT gateway or is it a NAT gateway configured via the AWS Console in the VPC section?) Anyway, `I am able to ssh into Mongodb instance...` is this from the nodejs server? If so, the most likely cause is that port 27017 is not included in the security group attached to your MongoDB instance (make sure it allows the private IP of your nodejs server only)

Comment: Yeah it does seem a bit messy! The EC2 instance is acting as a NAT gateway. I ssh through my Nodejs server instance. The security group for my Mongodb instance source is set to my Nodejs subnet CIDR block for ssh as well port 27017.    When you say "make sure it allows the private IP of your nodejs server" you're talking about the subnet cidr block like I have it right? Should I just totally ditch the NAT?

Comment: Yip, subnet CIDR block is good. You should be able to `telnet <mongo.private.ip.here> 27017` from your nodejs instance. (P.S Hoping xx-x-x-xx meant xx.x.x.xx, unless it was referring to the Private DNS) If you can't connect, perhaps it's a config on the OS (maybe additional `iptables` or `ufw` if ubuntu. `SELinux` if CentOS or variant like Amazon Linux (although I think disabled by default)? )

Comment: Thanks for all your help, this is one of these that is hard to help someone unless you see it all. Yeah I was referring to private dns. I've connected to a mongodb instance from a nodejs server on aws before when everything was public just to test it out. But now that I've made mongodb private I feel maybe it's my mongoose connection string in my nodejs code. Using linux by the way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173789/discussion-between-keenan-lawrence-and-brad-vanderbush).

Comment: Make sure your firewall allows the port

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-firewall-with-ufw-on-ubuntu-18-04

Answer (score 1):

Solution:
Changed my mongo.conf file 
from: 
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1

to:
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 0.0.0.0

Basically changed the bindIp: to 0.0.0.0  to allow any IP.